# Find the area between line and curve

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Point $A$ lies on the curve $g(x) = x$ And lies on a value $x > 0$. From point $A$ a line is drawn parallel to the $y$-axis. The second drawn graph is $f(x)=x^3$.

Calculate the coordinates of point $A$ so that the area of ​​$B$ and $C$ will be equal.

[image]

**x must be less than 1, according to this picture, right?** But I don't know how to get the point A.

[image]

Should I use this formula?

$$A_{C-B}=\int^{x}_{0} \pi x^{2}-\int^{x}_{0} \pi x^{6}$$, where $x<1$.

$$\int^{x}_{0} \pi x^{2}dx=\pi \int^{x}_{0} x^{2}dx=\pi \left[ \frac{x^{3}}{3} \right]^{x}_{0}  =\pi \left[ \left( \frac{x^{3}}{3} -\frac{0^{3}}{3} \right)  \right]  =\frac{\pi x^{3}}{3}$$

$$\int^{x}_{0} \pi x^{6}dx=\pi \int^{x}_{0} x^{6}dx=\pi \left[ \frac{x^{7}}{7} \right]^{x}_{0}  =\pi \left[ \left( \frac{x^{7}}{7} -\frac{0^{7}}{7} \right)  \right]  =\frac{\pi x^{7}}{7}$$

Comment: Why are you multiplying by $\pi?$

Comment: Are you comparing areas or volumes?

Comment: @Robert Z Oh my bad, pi is used for volumes.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find a volume of revolution. The problem is not asking for that, and you are not allowed to have $x$ as the upper bound if $x$ is the variable you are intergrating with respect to.

Answer (score 2):

Let abscissa of $A$ be $A_x$.

We need to calculate coordinates of $A$ such that area of $B$ = area of $C$
$$\begin{align}\implies& \int_0^{A_x} x^3 \ dx = \int_0^{A_x} x - x^3\ dx\\\implies &\frac{(A_x)^4}{4 } = \frac{(A_x)^2}{2} - \frac{(A_x)^4}{4}\\\implies & \frac{(A_x)^4}{2} = \frac{(A_x)^2}{2}\\\implies & (A_x)^2(A_x^2 - 1)  = 0\end{align}$$
Thus $A_x$ is $1$ indeed.

Therefore coordinates of $A$ are $(1, 1).$

---

I don't agree with the graph. But the [area of regions $B$ and $C$ are equal](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4maekduoac) when coordinates of $A$ are $(1, 1).$

Comment: How can we tell that the area of region B and C are equal when coordinates of A are (1,1)? On the first picture it seems like they've drawn a line parallel to y-axis, and not when x = 1.

Comment: Actually we are calculating the coordinates of $A$ such that the area of regions $B$ and $C$ are same. Assuming that for a specific abscissa $A_x$, we have area of $B$ equal to area of $C$, and so finding value of $A_x$ solves the task.

Comment: For your second question, I think the picture is just to make confusion. They've drawn a line parallel to y-axis randomly somewhere, and not when x = 1 to make you solve the problem as they want it to be solved. If it were drawn parallel to $y$ axis when $x = 1$, won't even need the application of integration.